# how to read the text in tfw file?

Tags: python, gis, tiff

I'm trying to check a value in a [tfw file](http://www.cryer.co.uk/file-types/t/tfw.htm).
I have a lot of tfw files and I need to go through all of them in a loop and check if the value in the first line is equal to x.

I can't find anywhere how to work with tfw files. I know it is like a text file (ASCII) but it's not working with `xxx.readlines`. Does someone know how can I read the first line?

EXAMPLE:

```
0.6 -----> I NEED TO CHECK THIS VALUE
0 
0 
-0.6
355000.317
459999.682
```

Comment: "``its not working with xxx.readlines``" - what's your error trace? Maybe use a different encoding? Please add your code and the error trace to your question.

Comment: Please share your relevant code and a sample of the file you try to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a text file you should be able to do it like this:

```
tfw_file = open("filename", "r")
tfw_raw_data = tfw_file.read()  #reading all text from file
tfw_file.close()
value_from_file = float(tfw_raw_data.split("\n")[0]) # splitting file by lines, getting first line and converting it to float
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below (if it is not working you will have to upload your input file to a public location so it can be tested against the code)

```
with open('tfw.txt','r') as tfw:
    x-scale= float(tfw.readlines()[0])
    print('x-scale value: {}'.format(x-scale))
```

Comment: with open('tfw.txt','r') as tfw: --> the end of the file is .tfw , not .txt

Comment: So change the file name to the right value as you have in your computer disk

Answer (score 0):

it works now:

```
    for filename in os.listdir(root):
     if filename.endswith('.tfw'):
      with open (os.path.join(root,filename)) as f:
      content = f.read()
      line = float(content.split("\n")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read just the first line of the file:

```
with open('data.tfw', 'r') as f:
    value = float(f.readline())

    print(f'Value: {value}')
```